# Video lags on ubuntu 16.04 (as well as in browser ) ( tried all possible ways )

Tags: 16.04, video, intel-graphics, browser, gpu-driver

I have switched from Windows 10 to ubuntu 16.04 a month before.

I 've never experienced this issue on win 10 (even h265 format).

My videos lags on ubuntu 16.04 (tried smplayer mplayer etc.) and on browsers (firefox and chrome both) .

Sites such as youtube, udemy, udacity, etc.

what are the possible ways to solve it?

My system info:

```
Memory: 5.7 GB

Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 


Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile // on Win 10 , used to be intel HD 
                                       Graphics


OS Type: 64 bit
```

Comment: You can try an Ubuntu 'family flavour' with a lighter desktop environment than standard Ubuntu: Lubuntu with the ultra-light LXDE, Ubuntu MATE with the medium light MATE or Xubuntu with the medium light XFCE. I think video will play better with these operating systems in your computer. Download the iso files and try them live. Install the flavour, that you like best, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Comment: @sudodus what's the issue with the current ubuntu installed?

Comment: The issue might be that standard Ubuntu needs a more powerful computer or particularly graphics chip. This may seem surprising because it works well with Windows. But the hardware developers are cooperating closely with the big commercial software companies, and the free software (linux) might lag behind; it takes time until efficient software is developed. This can be seen particularly with drivers and other software to manage hardware components and also peripheral devices.

Comment: @sudodus LOL and I installed ubuntu for faster performance :P

Comment: I like the ultra-light Lubuntu. Other people prefer Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE.